# System.MissingMethodException Message=Method not found: DryIoc.Rules DryIoc.Rules.WithoutFastExpressionCompiler()

Tags: c#, .net, prism, .net-standard-2.0, dryioc

I am using Prism.DryIoc.Extensions(v8.0.62) and Prism.DryIoc.Forms(v8.1.97) which internally is using DryIoc.dll v4.7.3 and v4.7.7 respectively for my Xamarin.Forms project.

I also have a nuget update for my project which is internally using DryIoc.dll v5.0.2.

Now, If I update project nuget to the latest, It throws error. As there is a version conflict.

Since it is a project related nuget, I will have to update somehow. But there is a dependency on Prism and Prism has not released any latest version with latest DryIoc.dll.

I tried to add the following in our .csproj file

```
<PackageReference Include="Prism.DryIoc.Extensions" Version="8.0.62">
        <ReferenceOutputAssembly>false</ReferenceOutputAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
          <assemblyIdentity name="DryIoc.dll" culture="neutral" />
          <bindingRedirect oldVersion="4.7.3" newVersion="5.0.2" />
        </dependentAssembly>
    </PackageReference>
```

This solved compile time error but started throwing run time error as below,

> System.MissingMethodException   Message=Method not found: DryIoc.Rules
> DryIoc.Rules.WithoutFastExpressionCompiler()

I also tried creating app.config and use the below code snippet,

```
<configuration>
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="DryIoc" publicKeyToken="dfbf2bd50fcf7768" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.0.1.0" newVersion="5.0.2.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

But this is also failing with the same error as above.

Getting rid of Prism is one of the solutions but It is a huge effort as the entire project is using Prism.

What is the best possible solution to fix this? Please help me in this regard.

Comment: Where is your github repo plz ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prism's [open source](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism), you can modify parts to use DryIoc 5 and use those dlls.

It's not like you're *forced* to use nuget packages, they're meant to help. If they hinder, get rid of them.

Comment: Prism.DryIoc.Forms is using DryIoc.dll in DryIocContainerExtension. I cloned their repo, updated DryIoc.dll to 5.0.2 and built it, Found that WithoutFastExpressionCompiler has been removed in DryIoc.dll latest. So removed the method and created a dll and started using in my project. It started working. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Prism.DryIoc.Forms is using DryIoc.dll in DryIocContainerExtension. [Prism](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism) is an open source, Hence, I cloned the repo, updated DryIoc.dll to 5.0.2 and built it, Found that WithoutFastExpressionCompiler has been removed in DryIoc.dll latest. So removed the method and created a dll and started using in my project. It started working.