# DryIoC with Prism crashes on HUAWEI only

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism, dryioc

I am facing the following error on my Xamarin.Forms app.

```
Interpreter.TryInterpretAndUnwrapContainerException (DryIoc.IResolverContext r, FastExpressionCompiler.LightExpression.Expression expr, System.Boolean useFec, System.Object& result)
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Interpreter.TryInterpretAndUnwrapContainerException (DryIoc.IResolverContext r, FastExpressionCompiler.LightExpression.Expression expr, System.Boolean useFec, System.Object& result)
Container.ResolveAndCacheKeyed (System.Int32 serviceTypeHash, System.Type serviceType, System.Object serviceKey, DryIoc.IfUnresolved ifUnresolved, System.Object scopeName, System.Type requiredServiceType, DryIoc.Request preResolveParent, System.Object[] args)
IResolver.Resolve (System.Type serviceType, System.Object serviceKey, DryIoc.IfUnresolved ifUnresolved, System.Type requiredServiceType, DryIoc.Request preResolveParent, System.Object[] args)
Resolver.Resolve (DryIoc.IResolver resolver, System.Type serviceType, System.Object[] args, DryIoc.IfUnresolved ifUnresolved, System.Type requiredServiceType, System.Object serviceKey)
DryIocContainerExtension.Resolve (System.Type type, System.ValueTuple`2[System.Type,System.Object][] parameters)
DryIocContainerExtension.Resolve (System.Type type, System.ValueTuple`2[System.Type,System.Object][] parameters)
PrismApplicationBase.<ConfigureViewModelLocator>b__19_0 (System.Object view, System.Type type)
ViewModelLocationProvider.AutoWireViewModelChanged (System.Object view, System.Action`2[T1,T2] setDataContextCallback)
ViewModelLocator.OnAutowireViewModelChanged (Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject bindable, System.Object oldValue, System.Object newValue)
BindableObject.SetValueActual (Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty property, Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject+BindablePropertyContext context, System.Object value, System.Boolean currentlyApplying, Xamarin.Forms.Internals.SetValueFlags attributes, System.Boolean silent)
ViewModelLocator.SetAutowireViewModel (Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject bindable, System.Nullable`1[T] value)
PageUtilities.SetAutowireViewModel (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement element)
PageNavigationService.CreatePageFromSegment (System.String segment)
PageNavigationService.ProcessNavigationForRootPage (System.String nextSegment, System.Collections.Generic.Queue`1[T] segments, Prism.Navigation.INavigationParameters parameters, System.Nullable`1[T] useModalNavigation, System.Boolean animated)
PageNavigationService.ProcessNavigation (Xamarin.Forms.Page currentPage, System.Collections.Generic.Queue`1[T] segments, Prism.Navigation.INavigationParameters parameters, System.Nullable`1[T] useModalNavigation, System.Boolean animated)
App.OnInitialized ()
AsyncMethodBuilderCore+<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__7_0 (System.Object state)
```

What is interesting, based on AppCenter crashes, it only happens on Huawei devices with Android 9 or 10. I am wondering if anyone has any clue/tip what is going wrong?

*System info*

- Xamarin.Forms 5.0.0.2125
- Prism 8.1.97
- Prism.DryIoc.Forms 8.1.97

Comment: What is the actual exception message or inner exception message? I see only a stack trace.

Comment: It crashes with lovely NullReferenceException. Unfortunately. as stated above, this is coming from AppCenter and I don't know much more...

Answer (score 0):

The NRE does not provide a lot of info :-(
Also, this Prism version uses the old DryIoc version, which complicates the investigation.

As of Today, in principle, you may fork the Prism.DryIoc.Forms, update it to the latest DryIoc v5.0.2 (**but instead of DryIoc.dll package use the DryIoc source package**). Then reference the Prism directly in your project and put the breakpoint in `TryInterpretAndUnwrapContainerException`. Check the comment under this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/72258242/2492669.

I will be interested to find out the real cause of this issue as well.

Comment: If you have no Huawei at hand for testing, you can manually report information that might be interesting to AppCenter instead of the break point.